# Sci-fi movie from the early 80's

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi

There is a move from the 80's about a (royal?) alien family who crash landed their space craft out in rural or maybe farm land area; they are being chased by a killer. They crash near a family that ends up helping them.

I think the family was a father and mother, daughter, and grand parents. The family is humanoid, or more human looking--not little green creatures. The family has a body guard that is in an all black armored suit, I think I remember it had maybe a tail, and shot a laser gun.

The killer kills the bodyguard, stabs or shoots it, and I think I remember that instead of blood, it was similar to a light color (white) silly string that shoots out of the wound.

Comment: [Earthbound](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082308/)?

Answer (score 4):

This is [Stranded](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094050/) from 1987.

> A young woman and her grandmother living in an isolated farmhouse are
>   kidnapped by aliens.

You can see the alien bodyguard get shot here. Note the amazing special effects.

[image]