# Obscure 1980s movie about an alien family and their android bodyguard who get stranded on Earth

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

Trying to find this 1980s movie about an alien family who got stranded on Earth. They're like refugees of sorts and are being hunted by another species of alien. They have this kind of android as a bodyguard, who has tentacle-like appendages as weapons.

Answer (score 9):

*Stranded* (1987)?

It has the alien family showing up on Earth while escaping hunters and the robot guard, although from the bits I've watched I only saw a wrist gun.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stranded_(1987_film)):

> A grandmother and granddaughter who live on a remote farm in the remote American South find themselves hostages of **a family of aliens who crash land near their home. The aliens are escapees from a war torn world hoping to hide on earth,** but due to a misunderstanding the aliens kill the granddaughter's boyfriend. This leads to their discovery, and they are attacked by locals.
>
> The locals have been worked into a frenzy by the father of the boy killed, a local hothead, and the situation devolves into a hostage situation. Hollis McMann, an African-American sheriff tries to control the situation and get everyone, aliens included, out alive but **his efforts are made more difficult by the alien family's robot guard, an alien assassin from the family's home world** and the prejudice of the locals and his own deputies.

---

Found by searching this site for `[story-identification] alien bodyguard` which turned up [Sci-fi movie from the early 80's](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/168787) - I knew that plot sounded familiar.

Comment: If this is the right answer, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left.